# How can I make a piece of armor give the player no protection?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've tried commands around this concept, but couldn't wrap my head around the NBT data for them.

```
/replaceitem entity @p armor.feet minecraft:iron_boots 1
```

I want iron boots that don't actually do anything and are only cosmetic. How can I go about doing that?

Answer (score 8):

Armor has an NBT value called operation, accessed like this:

`{AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0}]}`

Operation is a value for how much armor protects the player. Operation:0 means the armor is purely cosmetic.

Try this:

`/give @s minecraft:iron_boots{AttributeModifiers:[{Operation:0}]}`

Comment: Your command *works*, however, you show a clear misunderstanding of what `Operation` does. It's part of the attribute modifier system, and the `Operation` tag is completely different from what you describe it as here. Due to evidence of a misunderstanding of what `Operation` does, I'm afraid I'll have to give this post a negative vote. I'd like you to familiarize yourself with how the attribute modifiers field works, edit your post to correctly describe it, and I'll be happy to change my vote to an upvote. Thanks!